# How to ignore the semgrep check in this condition

Tags: go, github, semgrep

My code as following:

```
// nosemgrep: go.lang.security.audit.dangerous-exec-command.dangerous-exec-command
func run(path string) error {
    cmd := exec.Command(path)
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    return cmd.Run()
}
```

But no help.
And the I config a .semgrepignore such as the following:

```
# Common large paths
launcher/
```

Nothing help also.

The error when github ci checking is :

```
  go.lang.security.audit.dangerous-exec-command.dangerous-exec-command     
          Detected non-static command inside Command. Audit the input to        
  'exec.Command'. If unverified                                                 
          user data can reach this call site, this is a code injection          
  vulnerability. A malicious                                                    
          actor can inject a malicious script to execute arbitrary code.        
          Details: https://sg.run/W8lA                                          
                                                                                
           37┆ cmd := exec.Command(path)
                            
  BLOCKING CODE RULES FIRED:
    go.lang.security.audit.dangerous-exec-command.dangerous-exec-command
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue with python and solved the issue by putting the suppression on the same line instead of above the function

```
subprocess.getoutput(<code here>) # nosemgrep: python.lang.security.audit.dangerous-subprocess-use.dangerous-subprocess-use
```